# Need Average of Col 1 between two date range and update Col 2 from same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate, average

I need to get the 14 days average Col 1 and update Col 2 of the same table. So if you look at Col 2, I need to get that 18.2% average percentage with Col 1 data between 10/29 and 11/15 date range on column today. I am so confused as to how to group this kind of function in an update statement. Anyone has a clue?

TABLE 1

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═════╦════════╦════════╗
║    Today   ║    Date     ║Hours║ Col 1  ║ Col 2  ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 10/29/2014 ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 220 ║        ║        ║       
║ 10/30/2014 ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 220 ║        ║        ║       
║ 10/31/2014 ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 200 ║        ║        ║       
║ 11/1/2014  ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 200 ║        ║        ║       
║ 11/2/2014  ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 200 ║  9.09% ║        ║       
║ 11/3/2014  ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 200 ║  9.09% ║        ║       
║ 11/4/2014  ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 160 ║ 20.00% ║        ║       
║ 11/5/2014  ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 160 ║ 20.00% ║        ║       
║ 11/6/2014  ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 160 ║ 20.00% ║        ║       
║ 11/7/2014  ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 160 ║ 20.00% ║        ║       
║ 11/8/2014  ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 120 ║ 25.00% ║        ║       
║ 11/9/2014  ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 120 ║ 25.00% ║        ║       
║ 11/10/2014 ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 120 ║ 25.00% ║        ║       
║ 11/11/2014 ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 120 ║ 25.00% ║        ║       
║ 11/12/2014 ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 100 ║ 16.67% ║        ║       
║ 11/13/2014 ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 100 ║ 16.67% ║        ║       
║ 11/14/2014 ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 100 ║ 16.67% ║        ║       
║ 11/15/2014 ║ 11/15/2014  ║ 100 ║ 16.67% ║ 18.92% ║       
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: There is little to no chance anybody can help you with such little information provided. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to get started.

Comment: I basically need a 14 days cumilative average of Col 1 in Col 2

Comment: Thanks for formatting my table **abatishchev**

Comment: @sql_dev1802, which 14 days, any 14 days starting from today backwards?

Comment: Yes. 14days from Today column. -14days from current date. For example, on 11/12 i need 11/12 - 14 days average of 'col1' in col2. its quite complex sorry hope i made it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to store the average value as decimal instead of varchar , as % can be added in presentation layer.

Here is the query that does the calculation, substring and cast was needed as average column is varchar.

EDIT: 
removed substring logic, as they are float columns, as per OP comments.

```
update myTable
set [col 2] = T.avgValue
from (
select avg( [col 1] ) as avgValue
from mytable
where datediff(day,[Today],'2014-11-15 00:00:00') <=14 ) T
where datediff(day,[Today],'2014-11-15 00:00:00') <=14
```

EDIT:

As this needs to be done for each date, it can be done using cursor

```
declare @dateval datetime
declare tempcur cursor for
select today from mytable

open tempcur 
fetch next from tempcur  into @dateval
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin


update myTable
set [col 2] = T.avgValue
from (
select avg( [col 1] ) as avgValue
from mytable
where datediff(day,myTable.[Today],@dateval) <=14 
and today <= @dateval
) T
where today = @dateval


fetch next from tempcur  into @dateval

end
close  tempcur
deallocate  tempcur
```

Comment: Thanks. I have both Col 1 and Col 2 as FLOAT and need the result in decimals for now. Later I would change the display format in SSRS. One concern on your suggestion. I need Past 14 day average on any date not just today. Sorry if I had confused you. Any day from'Today' Column should have a corresponding past 14 days average of Col 1 in Col 2.

Comment: @sql_dev1802, removed substring part and added date to datediff, so it works for 14 days from 2014-11-15

Comment: Am afraid this does nt seem to work. It only updates 11/15 dates on the Today field. I need it for all days in the today col. Each day should have past 14day average.

Comment: @sql_dev1802, does each day should have same average , or need to calculate the average again for each one starting from that day backwards

Comment: @sql_dev1802, if same average, i updated the answer.

Comment: need to calculate the average again for each one starting from that day backwards

Comment: Using cursor would be a great option, but my table has more than 100,000 rows and using cursor would slow down the processing time. Can we use a temp table instead or something else?